# Send notification from abstract class' static method in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to send a Slack notification using Laravel 5.8, everything worked well with my other classes but I now need to send a notification from a static method, however I can't call `notify()` from a static method:

`$this->notify(new ErrorOccured($errorMessage));`

and we can't call a non-static method from a static method like such:
`self::notify();`

Is there another way I don't know of, which permits this?

Comment: yes, you've got to make an instance of the class in order to use a non-static method :) .. so `$claz = new Claz; $clas->notify();`

Comment: Basically you should be using events and send the notifications from a single event listener. This is off-topic but a better way to handle notifications.

Comment: Hmm good point @Rehmat.. I never used events and don't know how they work yet but it might be my solution

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper they are super easy to work with. Have a look at official documentation. If you prefer, I'll post an answer.

Comment: I'll check the docs, but you can still post an answer so that there is one less unanswered question on Stackoverflow! That will possibly take a long time to write however, so you might want to reconsider.